# How to send push notifications to IOS devices via Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: connected-apps, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, mobilepush

I created a connected app with Push Messaging enabled and the "Android GCM" option selected for the Supported Push Platform.  For the api key, I am using the legacy key of my Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) project.  This allows me to send notifications to my android app from the Test Push Notifications page in Salesforce without issue.

I have configured my FCM project to also support my IOS app.  In IOS, I am able to sign in with my connected app and register for push notifications successfully using my FCMToken (I did have to change the "ServiceType" parameter that the mobile sdk sends when registering, though).

Now on the Test Push Notifications page, my IOS logins show up in the Recipients lookup and when I send the test notification I get a "Success" message.  The phone, however, never receives the notification.

I was able to successfully send a notification to the IOS phone from the Firebase console as well as the Firebase rest api, so the problem seems to be somewhere between Salesforce and Firebase.

Has anyone been able to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish?  Does anybody have any ideas as to why I'm not getting the notification on the phone?

Comment: Can you edit your post to clarify what FCM is?  Is it Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Comment: Edited the post, hopefully that clears things up a little bit.  Please let me know any other questions you may have!

Comment: Hey Alex, I'm trying to figure all this out as well. When you create the connected app, there's no choice for FCM, so I chose GCM and plugged in the API Key from my FCM. I can't send a test message: it gives me a Google Cloud Messaging authentication error. Have you been able to find any answers?

Comment: Be sure to use the **legacy server key**, not the normal server key.  I am able to send test messages to android devices using this setup, but I still have not been able to send anything to an ios device.